# COUNTIFS with date range and criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, sumifs

I have a number of arrays to work through and need specified results per month according to what contractor and month is being queried.

However, the COUNTIFS statement I am trying to use only returns a #VALUE.

Contractor = the table list of contractor entries. D8 = the manually entered data of which contractor is to be looked up. ReportedDate = a table list of dates.

In breaking down this formula, both halves work however they don't work together for some reason.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

COUNTIFS, SUMIFS, SUMPRODUCT seem to yield the same result.

**DOESN'T WORK ->**

```
    =COUNTIFS(ReportedforMonthEnd,">=5/1/2018",ReportedforMonthEnd,"<6/1/2018",Contractor,D8)
```

**WORKS ->**

```
    =COUNTIFS(Contractor, D8)
```

**WORKS ->**

```
    =COUNTIFS(ReportedforMonthEnd,">=2018/5/1",ReportedforMonthEnd,"<2018/6/1")
```

**UPDATE** Ugh, I literally tried to make an example for you... and it worked on the example. So now I need to figure out why it isn't working in the main version. Everything is formatted the same so what would cause it?

```
    =COUNTIFS(ReportedforMonthEnd1,">=2018/4/1",ReportedforMonthEnd1,"<2018/5/1",Contractor1,D8)
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PKr3.png)

Comment: Are `contractor` and `ReportedforMonthEnd` the same size and shape?

Comment: @JohnPhillips, try to provide an example so people can reproduce and understand better the problem. Please check this link: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ScottCraner Contractor & Reported for Month end are the same size and shape of a table header and 497 entries each.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks, that makes more sense.